# sql trigger to set field value from another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set trigger to the sql to update value of a gf with a value from field "title" inside table c_p_r, but getting an error in syntax. Can someone point me where I am wrong?

```
  CREATE TRIGGER setgf
    AFTER UPDATE ON c_p_r
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      TRUNCATE gf
      UPDATE gf
      SET gf = title
      FROM c_p_r
```

This thing is answering me with

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE gf
  SET gf = title
  FROM c_p_r' at line 5
```

Can someone point me where I am wrong with it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And why would you be using `truncate`?

Comment: Start by using `;` to end your statements. And the `BEGIN` misses a corresponding `END`. But even then I guess your trigger won't compile or make sense. E.g. if by `TRUNCATE` you meant the [statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/truncate-table/), `TABLE` is missing. If the [function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/truncate/) was meant, it doesn't set anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` sql query is malformed. Also if you are trying to copy one field value to another field during update. You should use BEFORE UPDATE handler. I would write the query like below:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER setgf
    BEFORE UPDATE ON c_p_r
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SET NEW.gf = COALESCE(NEW.gf, NEW.title); //this will take care of not overriding the gf if it was part of update statement
    END
```